# Run fish shell functions via i3 keybinding

Tags: fish

I wrote a simple fish function which lists out an output of locating command within rofi and the selected option is fed to vim.

```
function myfunction
    vim ( locate ~/str/Dotfiles | rofi -dmenu )
end
```

and inside i3 config file, I have:

```
bindsym $mod+c exec myfunction
```

Well, nothing happens when I press <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> but the function runs fine inside a terminal. Is it simply impossible to run a user defined fish function outside of a terminal?

Comment: Faho's answer should solve your problem. But note that unless you have done something like alias `vim` to `vim -g` or `gvim` it won't work since plain vim must be run in a terminal window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it simply impossible to run a user defined fish function outside of a terminal?

It's certainly possible.

My best guess is that i3 here is launching a different shell (e.g. /bin/sh or whatever you have set up as your user's default shell via `chsh`).

Try explicitly specifying fish via:

```
bindsym $mod+c exec fish -c myfunction
```